# Sub Consulta dentro de un OPENQUERY - SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, transact-sql

Tengo la siguiente consulta, al utilizar un OPENQUERY he podido introducir una variable externa

Ejemplo:

```
Declare @Variable VARCHAR(30) = '303050'

DECLARE @TSQL VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @TSQL = '
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(CONEXION,''
SELECT 
 CU.CODIGO
,CU.NOMBRE

FROM TABLA CU
WHERE CU.CODIGO = '''''+CONVERT(CHAR(30),@Variable)+'''''
'')'

EXEC(@TSQL)
```

Y listo, me funciona perfecto , me trae un cliente en especifico segun el que especifique en la variable, sin embargo a veces quiero hacer la consulta para varios registros y me veo en la obligacion de usar un Cursor, en el cual voy guardando en esa variable uno a uno el codigo de cliente

Es posible que en vez de meter la variable en duro y usar un cursor, poder meter una SubConsulta de otra tabla

Ejemplo

```
DECLARE @TSQL VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @TSQL = '
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(CONEXION,''
SELECT 
 CU.CODIGO
,CU.NOMBRE

FROM TABLA CU
WHERE CU.CODIGO = '''''+( SELECT CODIGO FROM TABLA2 )+'''''
'')'

EXEC(@TSQL)
```

la consulta de arriba es solo una prueba, solo quiero saber si dentro de un OPENQUERY es posible meter una SubConsulta a otra tabla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una forma rápida de hacerlo es cambiar la consulta y meter una enumeración de valores en la misma, por ejemplo:

```
DECLARE @TSQL VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @TSQL = '
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(CONEXION,''
SELECT 
 CU.CODIGO
,CU.NOMBRE

FROM TABLA CU
WHERE CU.CODIGO IN ('
+  STUFF((SELECT ',' + CAST(CODIGO AS VARCHAR)
            FROM TABLA2
             FOR XML PATH('')
         ),1,1,''
        )
+')'')'

EXEC(@TSQL)
```

De esa manera añades los diferentes valores de `CODIGO`, separados por coma, dentro de una selección múltiple (`CU.CODIGO in (1,2,...)`). La función `STUFF` solo está para quitar la primera coma.

Si `CODIGO` es xCHAR cambia muy ligeramente:

```
+  STUFF((SELECT ',' + '''''' + CODIGO + ''''''
            FROM TABLA2
             FOR XML PATH('')
         ),1,1,''
        )
```